# SQL - Summing aggregate sub query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sum, subquery, case

This is the code I have

```
select  distinct sli.order_no,
            sli.pkg_no,
            case when line.primary_ind = 'Y' then sum(paid_amt) else 0 end  as paid_amt,
            line.pkg_li_no,     
            sum(case when sli.perf_no = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as num_seats_pur,
            sli.status
    from    t_sub_line sli
    left outer join t_line line on sli.li_seq_no = line.li_seq_no
    where sli.order_no in (1,2)
    group by
            sli.order_no,
            sli.pkg_no,
            line.primary_ind,
            line.pkg_li_no,
            sli.status  
    having  line.primary_ind = 'Y'
```

This code produces this output

```
order_no pkg_no paid_amt    pkg_li_no   num_seats_pur   status
1        322    124.00      967          2              7
1        322    -124.00     992          2              4
2        854    253.00      952          1              7
2        854    -253.00     996          1              4
```

what I really need for the data to return is the following. I need the sum of paid_amt field.

```
order_no pkg_no paid_amt    pkg_li_no   num_seats_pur   status
1        322    0       967              2              7
2        854    0       996              1              4
```

even if i change status to be max(status) so its not grouping on it. I don't have sum_paid amt.

when i try this code:

```
sum(case when line.primary_ind = 'Y' then sum(paid_amt) else 0 end)  as paid_amt,
```

I get the following error message

```
Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.
```

Comment: Why did you pick those values of pkg_li_no and status?

Comment: @CaiusJard It is a nested query, it is used to join on (to the outer/parent query). pkg_li_no and order_no

Comment: Did you try the following line, by moving the sum outside (removing the sum inside the case statement)? I don't think you can get a sum of sums, though I haven't tried it before:   sum(case when line.primary_ind = 'Y' then paid_amt else 0 end) as paid_amt

Comment: @TinyHaitian I did not, but I just tried it and the nested query comes back with the same values. The idea is we need to suppress a handful of records where the sum of sums is zero. I can't figure out a different way to do this

Comment: Ah ok.  I think I see what @CaiusJard is trying to ask.  I think the sum will help; however, what determines which pkg_li_no or status to pick when trying to flatten your results? As it stands, it doesn't look like you have anything telling it which one to pick, so summing won't happen correctly.

Comment: In other words, when you're summing, how will it know to pick status number 7 or 4 for package_no 322? How will it know to pick pkg_li_no 967 or 922 for package_no 322?

Comment: Maybe you should make sure the appropriate joins are done inside the nested query also?

Comment: Can you supply sample data?

Comment: I meant "in your desired output, you had a choice of 7 or 4 for status. Why did pkgno 322 get status 7 and pkgno 854 get status 4? One is the max and one is the min. It is not consistent and is hard to code for". Same for pkg_li_no - you picked the max for one and the min for another. Why? (First we must determine the algorithm in your head before we can turn it into sql )

Comment: I can remove the status  or even set it to max, that isn't the issue. The issue is i can't remove pkg_li_no, because that is what is used on the outer join, and that is what is prohibiting the summing.

Comment: Grouping by LineItem doesn't make much sense. Try to enhance your grouping list. Start with removing pkg_li_no from grouping list and it should do the trick. Also, if you can't do the Sum inside the CASE clause, try to use CTEs or Temptables

Answer (score 1):

A couple things you need to do.

1. Comment out pkg_li_no from the select and group by
2. Change the having statement to be included in the where statement
3. Remove the case from paid_amt since it is not necessary

> ```
>   select  distinct sli.order_no,
>                     sli.pkg_no,
>                     sum(paid_amt)as paid_amt,
>                   --  line.pkg_li_no,     
>                     sum(case when sli.perf_no = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as num_seats_pur,
>                     sli.status
>             from    t_sub_line sli
>             left join t_line line on sli.li_seq_no = line.li_seq_no
>             where sli.order_no in (1,2)
>             and  line.primary_ind = 'Y'
>             group by
>                     sli.order_no,
>                     sli.pkg_no,
>                     line.primary_ind,
>                    -- line.pkg_li_no,
>                     sli.status
> ```

**Other notes:**
I am not sure you want to select or group by the pkg_no or status, but you know more what outcome are looking for.  If they are different values, there will be different records.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish, but it seems that you overthinking the query. Try to simplifying it. 
FYI `HAVING` happens after the grouping, `WHERE` happens before the grouping, you don't even need the `CASE`

```
select  distinct sli.order_no,
            sli.pkg_no,
            sum(paid_amt) as paid_amt, 
            sum(case when sli.perf_no = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as num_seats_pur,
            sli.status
    from    t_sub_line sli
    left outer join t_line line on sli.li_seq_no = line.li_seq_no
    where sli.order_no in (1,2)
      and line.primary_ind = 'Y'
    group by
            sli.order_no,
            sli.pkg_no,
            sli.status
```